# Loading webpack bundles with hased filenames

Tags: webpack

This may be a dumb question, I want to load webpack bundles with hashed filenames without adjusting the -tag all the time

So in my index.html I would like to write

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

which loads something like `/app.a76gs0ad5dh45sdh9aa.js.`

I could use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to generate index.html file but I want to know is there other way to do that ?

I have tried to use `webpack-manifest-plugin` but it's not work. ( May be I'm wrong)

My webpack config

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //   title: 'Caching'
    // })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361677/3085279

Comment: @TanDuong Thank you, I already knew that plugin, I am finding an other solution without copy and create new index.html file

Comment: @ToujouAya did you ever find a good solution for this?  Working on something similar, but don't want to generate the new index everytime as well